# Directories will list, but are not recognize by cd

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, terminal

New to terminal and having problems out of the gate. Using Terminal 2.1.2 on a Mac running 10.6.8. Using the "ls Documents" will list the contents, but when I try to change directories, which I tried several different ways, I get the following results:

```
new-host-2:~ MDimond$ cd.
-bash: cd.: command not found

new-host-2:~ MDimond$ cd./Users/MDimond/Documents
-bash: cd./Users/MDimond/Documents: No such file or directory

new-host-2:~ MDimond$ cd. /Documents
-bash: cd.: command not found
```

The /usr/bin has the cd command listed; the /bin does not.

Comment: try cd followed by space then the directory name. e.g. `cd Documents`

Answer (score 3):

You typed `cd.` (with dot) instead of `cd`. Omit the dot (and the slash after it) and it should work.

Comment: `PATH` has nothing to do with this question. `cd` is a “built-in” (or “builtin”) command in the shell, i.e., it is not a program in `/bin`, `/usr/bin`, or any other directory (in contrast to _programs_ like `ls`, `cat`, and pretty much anything else you use) – so the shell does not need to search to find `cd`. The water is muddied by the fact that some systems _do_ have a `/bin/cd` or `/usr/bin/cd`, but those are red herrings – see [Why is `cd` not a program?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/38808/23408), [Where is `cd`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/116955/23408), and related questions.

Comment: @Scott I am on OS X, and there actually is a `/usr/bin/cd`, but you are right: When I call `cd`, the built-in command is used. I was unaware of the difference between built-in and external `cd`.